# Formula where Number is constant

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have researched online everywhere and can't really find anything close to the formula I need. Hopefully anyone here will be able to help me out:

I need to add these sample numbers

```
A1     B1      C1     D1     E1
F2     B10     F8     B4     F4 = 28
```

Each group "F2", "B10" "F8" is each in a separate cell and I need the sum of the numbers only for the row.

Hope I make sense.

Comment: Is the content of the cells actually "F2", "B10" and so on? Will there only ever be a single letter before the numbers? You may want to take the time to [tread this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

For single letter start:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MID(A1:E1,2,10)))
```

[image]